# Find and save data from the text file until new line character

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains data separated by new line character.
I am looking for a specific line that has a path.
So file looks something like this

...
some data 
PATH=C:\test 
some data
...

I want to collect the path and save it to variable which is specified in front of word PATH.

Here is my current approach.

```
f = open('/root/TestConnect', "r")
data2 = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),os.path.getsize(f.name),access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
index = data2.find(find_str)
tempStr = repr(data2[index - 1:index + 25])

for line in tempStr:
    if line.strip() == '=':
        break
x = re.search(r'[\n]',tempStr).start()

for line in tempStr:  
    print x
if line.strip() == x:
    break
print line
```

I am facing multiple issue with my logic and implementation.

Issue 1:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start' 
I am not sure why re.search(r'[\n]',tempStr).start() is returning None

Issue 2:  I am very sure this is not the optimum way to extract the data, I would appreciate if you could show me how this can be done more efficiently.

How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is only one line with "PATH=" the following would work:

```
with open('/root/TestConnect', "r") as config_file:
    for line in config_file:
        if 'PATH=' in line:
            path = line.strip().replace('PATH=','')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"\s*PATH\s*=\s*(.+)")
with open('/root/TestConnect', "rt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m = r.match(line)
        if m is not None:
            print m.group(1)
```

Comment: I think you forgot break after print, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @user3054204 If you want to display on the first occurrence of the PATH value than `print` must be followed by `break`. If you want to display all occurrences then the code can stay unchanged.